# Get contents from HTML tag using MyParser in Perl

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I have a html as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<h1>foo.c</h1>

<form method="post" action=""
        enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  Compare this file to the similar file: 
  <select name="file2">

    <option value="...">...</option>


  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="file1" value="foo.c" /><br>
  Show the results in this format: 
</form>
<hr>

<p>
<pre>
some code
</pre>
```

I need to get value of input name = 'file' and the contents of HTML pre tag. I don't know on perl language, by googling I wrote this small program(that I believe isn't "elegant"):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyParser;
use base qw(HTML::Parser);

#Store the file name and contents obtaind from HTML Tags
my($filename, $file_contents);

#This value is set at start() calls
#and use in text() routine..
my($g_tagname, $g_attr);


#Process tag itself and its attributes
sub start {
    my ($self, $tagname, $attr, $attrseq, $origtext) = @_;

    $g_tagname = $tagname;
    $g_attr = $attr;
}

#Process HTML tag body
sub text {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;

    #Gets the filename
    if($g_tagname eq "input" and $g_attr->{'name'} eq "file1") {
    $filename = $attr->{'value'};
    }

    #Gets the filecontents
    if($g_tagname eq "pre") {
    $file_contents = $text;
    }
}

package main;

#read $filename file contents and returns
#note: it works only for text/plain files.
sub read_file {
    my($filename) = @_;
    open FILE, $filename or die $!;
    my ($buf, $data, $n);
    while((read FILE, $data, 256) != 0) {
    $buf .= $data;
    }
    return ($buf);
}


my $curr_filename = $ARGV[0];
my $curr_file_contents = read_file($curr_filename);

my $parser = MyParser->new;
$parser->parse($curr_file_contents);

print "filename: ",$filename,"file contents: ",$file_contents;
```

Then I call `./foo.pl html.html` But I'm getting empty values from `$filename` and `$file_contents` variables.

How to fix this?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like always, there's more than one way to do it. Here's how to use the [DOM Parser](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) of [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) for this task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

# slurp all lines at once into the DOM parser
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <> });

print $dom->at('input[name=file1]')->attr('value');
print $dom->at('pre')->text;
```

Output:

```
foo.c
some code
```

Comment: Since the OP has an input file given as an argument, either the "magic open" diamond operator (`do { local $/; <> }`) or else using `Mojo::Util::slurp($ARGV[0])` makes more sense here. Otherwise, nice demo!

Comment: @memowe thanks for your answer as it just helped me out with a similar issue, but you have a typo in your answer - should be ->attr('value') not attrs. regards

Comment: @AndyLorenz Yep, you're right. It was `attrs` in the past, the code worked. Feel free to update it. :)

Comment: @memowe I've tried to edit your answer but fails with a javsacript error!  same error in both chrome and IE - seems to be an issue in the coding logic for an edit involving less than 6 character's worth of change.

Answer (score 5):

Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) `Perl` module ( very few lines ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( <> );
print $tree->findvalue( '//input[@name="file1"]/@value' );
print $tree->findvalue( '//pre/text()' );
```

**USAGE**

```
./script.pl file.html
```

**OUTPUT**

```
foo.c
some code
```

**NOTES**

- in the past, I was using `HTML::TreeBuilder` module to do some web-scraping. Now, I can't go back to complexity. `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` do all the magic with the useful [Xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion%3aXPath) expressions.
- you can use `new_from_file` method to open a file or a filehandle instead of `new_from_content`, see `perldoc HTML::TreeBuilder` ( `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` inherit methods from `HTML::TreeBuilder`)
- using `<>` in this way is allowed here because `HTML::TreeBuilder::new_from_content()` specifically allows reading multiple lines in that way. Most constructors will not allow this usage. You should provide a scalar instead or use another method.

Comment: Added _usage_ part, and replaced _DATA trick_ by a _diamond operator_ to open a file as argument.

Comment: Note for future readers: using `<>` in this way is allowed here because `HTML::TreeBuilder::new_from_content()` specifically allows reading multiple lines in that way. Most constructors will not allow this usage and will need `do { local $/; <> }` to read all the content into one variable (argument).

Answer (score 4):

You don't generally want to use plain HTML::Parser unless you're writing your own parsing module or doing something generally tricky. In this case, [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder), which is a subclass of HTML::Parser, is the easiest to use.

Also, note that HTML::Parser has a `parse_file` method (and HTML::TreeBuilder makes it even easier with a `new_from_file` method, so you don't have to do all of this `read_file` business (and besides, there are better ways to do it than the one you picked, including `File::Slurp` and the old `do { local $/; <$handle> }` trick.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($filename);

my $filename = $tree->look_down(
    _tag => 'input',
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'file1'
)->attr('value');

my $file_contents = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'pre')->as_trimmed_text;

print "filename: ",$filename,"file contents: ",$file_contents;
```

For information on `look_down`, `attr`, and `as_trimmed_text`, see the [HTML::Element](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aElement) docs; HTML::TreeBuilder both is a, and works with, elements.